Ways to distribute the seven deadly sins to a family of four
In a family there are four people. The cardinal sins/capital vices are distributed such that every person at least have one of them, but no members have the same sin.
Finally, no one has both acedia and avaritia. How many ways can this be distributed?
My solution was

All possible distribitions are $4!S(7,4)$.
Then, get how many possible combinations there is such that one has both acedia and avaritia:


First pick one person to give the the two sins to, can be done in $4$ ways.

Now distribute the 3 of the 5 sins left to the 3 remaining people, because each people have at least one sin: $\binom 5 {1,1,1}$ ways.

Finally we have 2 sins left which can be distributed in $\binom 4 2\cdot 2$ (choose two people out of four and then decide who gets which sin)


1-2 gives the wrong answer. I understand that the correct answer (which is that you subtract with $4!S(6,4)$, can be obtained because we can "fix" the acedia and avaritia as one when we distribute it. But why is my alternate answer wrong?

Whenever you fractionate distributions by first distributing one portion and then distributing another , you count wrongly, either overcounting or (as here) undercounting.
In your attempt,you are forgetting that the person who was allotted both acedia and avaritia, could also have some other sin, too
Thus the book's approach to subtract clubbed together acedia and avaritia and $5$ other sins distributed between all $4$ people is correct.

Hmm, ok. So what I did wrong was first distrbuting the 3 of 5 sins left, and then distributing the last 2?

Yes, that, plus assuming that the person with the two specified sins can't have any more.

If from unrestricted allotments, you wanted to subtract invalid allotments,  it would become quite complicated, viz $3!∗4[\binom52S2(3,3)+\binom51S2(4,3)+\binom50S2(5,3)]$

Hmm... I thought I didn't assume that the person with the two specified sins can't have anymore, because $\binom 4 2$ in my last step picks 2 people out of 4. Regardless, the main takeaway is that it is wrong to fractionate distibutions, thanks for making me realize that.

You're welcome !
